# Trouble downloading Windows Azure SDK 1.4

Tags: azure

I am trying to download the [Windows Azure SDK 1.4](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/sdk/).

The Web Platform Installer pops up, and I choose "add" for "Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 - August 2011". I click "accept" to the terms, and the installer downloads and tries to install the sdk.

I then get a message: "We're sorry. The following products have failed to install.", then lists everything I tried to download. It says that "this product cannot be installed because  product that it depends on did not install successfully."

[Download log available here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=LeEtsene).

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

To get around it I started uninstalling the previous versions of everything it was trying to install.  The installer worked after I'd unistalled the Visual Studio tool kit and the Azure SDK.

Fortunately when you rerun the WPI it doesn't try to re-download the files.

Comment: I did too. Uninstalling just the Azure SDK and then installing 1.4 worked for me. It was frustrating though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download the msi without the platform installer to skip the dependencies. 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28045